# Xamarin.Android does not support running the previous version. Please ensure your solution builds before running or debugging it

Tags: xamarin.forms

Please help I can't deploy my app on device. I'm trying to build a hello world app using xamarin forms. The app is successful when deploying on android emulator but when I deploy in my device Asus android 7.0 API 24 the deployment failed. I'm using VS 2015 community.

Comment: did you try to clean and build your portable class ?

Comment: Yes, I tried clean and rebuild still not working.

Comment: did you get any solutions?